# Is there a way to use TeX/LaTeX equations with the Xmind software?

Tags: math-mode, equations, mindmaps, software

I have used the [XMind](http://xmind.net/) mind mapping software and for years I have pasted png images of equations written in TeX/LaTeX into the topics to display complex equations.  Is there a way to generate equations directly in XMind?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This seems to be a question about input to XMind rather than doing anything compiled with TeX, so off-topic here really.  http://support.xmind.net/ may be a better place to ask, although an existing request seems to have been unfruitful http://support.xmind.net/customer/portal/questions/9797305-math-equation-support?b_id=14525

Comment: You could use instead http://equationmap.com/. It is very simple to use and **Save&Share** in `LaTeX`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Looks kike an awesome tool, but I don't use mind maps just to write equations.  I use it to structure ideas of which equations are occasionally a part of.  So this would not work for my purposes.  It is awesome nonetheless.

Comment: I hope that in future my suggest can to help you. Best regards.

Comment: It is open source, so you could always try to figure out a way to modify it yourself ;).

Comment: @cfr Yeah I wish I knew How to get started!  ... Like white on rice ...

Comment: Would it take .svg images? At least then they'd be scalable. Inkscape can convert pdf to svg on the command line  (piped from  pdftex perhaps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably out of luck with that. According to the [xmind support](https://xmind.desk.com/customer/en/portal/questions/16240606-math-equation-support)

> there are something fundamental issues that prevent implementing
>   rich-text support

Nevertheless, [you are not alone](https://github.com/xmindltd/xmind/issues/263), and an alternative apparently [exists](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-some-mind-mapping-app-that-allows-one-to-use-LaTex).

Comment: Yeah , I've been all over the XMnd developer and support sites and I've seen the alternative software. But I'm sort of locked in to XMind, as my maps are extremely large and apparently not importable. I thought maybe someone here could bring me joy.

Comment: LaTeX isn't exactly RTF, is it? Though presumably an entire TeX parser is unlikely to be easier that enabling bold and italics ;).

Comment: @cfr yeah that's over my head

Answer (score 6):

XMind 2020 version just launched the support for LaTeX (MathJax, to be precise). From the [Release Notes](https://www.xmind.net/xmind2020/release-notes/), version 2020.3.23:

> 3. LaTeX Equation - Insert professional equations right away, including mathematics and chemistry;

More Info: [FAQ – What command does XMind Equation Support?](https://www.xmind.net/faq/question/what-command-does-xmind-equation-support/)

Comment: Very good notice but this XMind 2020 is not free but it is necessary to pay.

Comment: Finally! Maybe they'll have a community version soon?

Comment: What´s a community version?, @grldsndrs

Comment: A community version would be a free version.